# AngularJs resizable border layout

Tags: angularjs

In my app, there is going to be a page that occupies the whole window (i.e. you can't scroll in any direction, the page resizes itself to the window size). I'm sure I can do some CSS trickery to achieve that, but this page is also going to contain some resizable areas. Basically there will be a sidebar that the user can make wider (within a min-max range).

Essentially what I'm trying to do is recreate [this page if you select "Border" under Basic Layouts](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html). I'm at a bit of a loss about how to do this. Should I try introducing some jQuery UI, or is there a purely AngularJS was to do it?

I know I haven't provided any code, so I'm not expecting anyone to give me the full working code. But a nudge in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a "pure" AngularJS way to do it without writing some new code or adding a framework to the mix such as you mentioned. I'd suggest looking at the more popular UI frameworks and see how they fit (maybe jQueryUI, or even Sencha).

Additionally, you sh/could write a directive to wrap your usage of the component to black-box it a bit more and be in the spirit of AngularJS (& so that you could more easily replace it in the future).

Given that type of functionality can be a bit tricky to create cross-browser (depending on browsers supported), it's probably best left to others who've done it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but guess it is what you wanted [AngularJS UI Layout](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout)

A borderlayout or splitterlayout plugin with AngularJS.